# Can I make the X-Ray mode even more transparent?

Tags: 3d-view, interface, transparency

I am currently modeling a small cabin using a reference photo.

My problem is that my objects are projected over the top of my reference photo, and even in X-ray mode it is hard to see my photo. Can I change the opacity of an object in X-Ray mode to make things behind it more visible?

In this case, I need to make my objects more transparent so I can use my reference photo to model it easier.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can change the x-ray opacity in the shading dropdown.
It's not exactly linear, but it works.

Or you can put the image in front and make it semi-transparent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Comment: Happy to help :).

Comment: @JachymMichal Can I make this opacity permanent? Because as soon as I come out of edit mode it turns to 0.5

Comment: Hi @NewBlenderer. It keeps the set value in my Blender 3.2. Switching between object/edit mode doesn't matter :). Not sure why yours doesn't.